# How to declare Vue data type

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to assign a datatype to data variable.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      var1:'',

  },
  methods:{

  },

  delimiters: ["[[","]]"],
});
```

How can I assign a datatype = Integer to `var1`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you don't. You could of course, use TypeScript for that but in plain javascript it's not made for this.

[Vue's api documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) explains this pretty clearly.

Comment: I tried using Number.isInteger(this.var1) but it always returns false even when var1 is an integer. Is there a easy Vue way to determine if var1 is an integer

Comment: Are you sure that var1 is actually an integer ? The way you assign it in your code example makes it look like you put a string there. Look at this to see how you should do it. https://jsfiddle.net/fvtnb6xj/

Comment: I used Number.isinteger(this.var1) in JS code and it did not work. Your code shows that it works in html code. Is there a way to check if a var is integer inside JS?